# Show that a function has the same period as another from a fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am looking at the following problem, and can intuitively see that it is true, but i am having trouble proving it:

Assume that the function $f$ is $2π$-periodic and has the Fourier series

> $$f(x)=a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin(nx))$$

Let $k \in N$. Show that the function $g(x) = f(kx)$ is $2π$-periodic, too.

All help is welcome!

Comment: Hi Seip, Welcome to Maths SE. You really don't need to get into the Fourier series, you just need to use $f(x+2n\pi) = f(x)$ (where $n$ is an integer), which is the definition of periodic.

Answer (score 1):

No need for Fourier series here ;)
$$g(x+2\pi n) = f(k(x+2\pi n)) = f(kx + 2\pi nk) = f(kx) = g(x)$$